# Importing data on website using ImportXML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

Trying to import the balance on this website

https://debank.com/profile/0x4e2a7d0e465d8d38aa5a1852d438e60b5832c1b4

The function im using is

`=IMPORTXML("https://debank.com/profile/0x4e2a7d0e465d8d38aa5a1852d438e60b5832c1b4","/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]")`

but then i get a error saying

Error
Imported content is empty.

Answer (score 2):

google sheet import formula does not support the scrapping of javascript elements

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use debank's own API and use this custom function:

#### Custom Function:

```
function getTotalBalance(user_id) {
  // replace key if you created your own account 
  var key = 'cee6f36d707cf3dfb48e8d857408ef14ec707efa'; 
  var url_balance = `https://pro-openapi.debank.com/v1/user/total_balance?id=${user_id}`;
  var params = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'AccessKey': key
    }
  };

  return JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_balance, params).getContentText()).total_usd_value;
}
```

#### Formula:

```
=getTotalBalance("0x4e2a7d0e465d8d38aa5a1852d438e60b5832c1b4", B1)
```

Where the parameters are the user_id and`B1` is a checkbox that would refresh the total balance if toggled.

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Simply go to https://open.debank.com/ and register an email to get 10000 units for free.
- Every balance fetch (toggle on checkbox) will cost you 150 units.
- If your units get exhausted, you can register another mail and use its new key if you dont want to spend money, or pay for additional units if you want.
  [image: price]
- You can use my key until it is exhausted. Note that the custom function won't automatically refresh, but you can use the checkbox method to refresh the value, or install a time trigger to refresh it on a specific time ***(I recommend using the checkbox method above since doing it on trigger and refresh it on intervals might exhaust your units faster than refreshing it manually when needed)***

#### Reference:

- https://docs.open.debank.com/en/reference/api-pro-reference/user